Composition of line / bar charts with horizontal layout
I'm currently working on MUI charts and wonder if it is possible to have both line and bar charts on the same container, with horizontal bar chart.
I have no issue to have the basic composition (see https://mui.com/x/react-charts/axis/#axis-direction).
As soon as i try with horizontal layout it broke everything
I first try to just add layout: "horizontal" on the bar series.
const series = [
  { type: 'line', dataKey: 'min', color: '#577399' },
  { type: 'line', dataKey: 'max', color: '#fe5f55' },
  { type: 'bar', layout: "horizontal", dataKey: 'precip', color: '#bfdbf7', yAxisId: 'rightAxis' },
];

It results with the error:
MUI X: The y-axis with id "rightAxis" should be of type "band" to display the bar series of id "auto-generated-id-2".

So i try to change the yAxis like that
          yAxis={[
            { id: 'leftAxis', reverse: reverseLeft },
            { id: 'rightAxis', scaleType: "band", reverse: reverseRight },
          ]}

But then i have the following error:
TypeError
_ is undefined

I try to switch axis and other things but it's not working at all. I did not find anything on the doc about this particular issue. Is it possible to do?
Thank you !
